# Filtering in foobar2000 (show .flac if available else other format)?

Tags: foobar2000, music-management

I would like to know if it is possible to filter albums with conditions in foobar2000. Here's an example. For this artist I have an album twice, one is in flac and the other one is in mp3, I like to have mp3 as they take less space when on the go on my phone and with my mediocre headphones. But at home I prefer listening to flac. What I would like to achieve is tell foobar to only show the flac/wav(lossless) version of this album if it is available, otherwise show the other version (any format). Is such a thing possible in foobar2000?

Example below

[image]

Comment: Are you looking to filter the MP3 duplicates albums from showing in your Media Library Viewer or just at the Playlist level? I've managed to filter Playlists this way, but only in the default UI.

Answer (score 1):

For what it's worth, I have a near-identical requirement: flac for listening on my desktop, ogg files sync'd to my phone.

When I ripped all the CDs in the first place I placed the flac files in subfolders `<albumname>/flac`. Then in foobar2000 I just prepend 'flac' to any search query.

It's not ideal, but having read the [docs](http://wiki.hydrogenaud.io/index.php?title=Foobar2000:Query_syntax) I don't think there's a way to specify the 'prefer flac and remove duplicates' behaviour.

Answer (score 1):

Create a separate library for FLAC or simply just search from FLAC when you are home?

I have multiple albums and I just search for FLAC if I want to play files that are only FLAC. You need to be in a foobar view media library and the filter visible.

Comment: Read over ["Why do I need 50 reputation to comment"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead) to ensure you understand how you can start commenting.